# Azure function timeTrigger is not present in portal

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function app running in Linux system. In it, I have create two functions, one is triggered by a blob trigger and the other with timetrigger.
Both functions are deployed with azure DevOps but when I go to portal, timetrigger function is not present.
To deploy the functions, I have the code in Git repository and it is copied to a .zip folder to build the artifact. Once artifact is built, it is deployed to function app with azure cli.

Code:

function.json

```
{
    "schedule": "0 30 14 * * *",
    "name": "myTimer",
    "type": "timerTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "runOnStartup": false
}
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 8,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 4,
      "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "-1",
  "retry": {
    "strategy": "fixedDelay",
    "maxRetryCount": 0,
    "delayInterval": "00:00:05"
  }
    
}
```

**init**.py

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**SOLUTION**
I had wrong configured function.json file. Correct content is:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
    "schedule": "0 30 14 * * *",
    "name": "myTimer",
    "type": "timerTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "runOnStartup": false
}
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for confirming @vll1990,
*Posting the solution as an answer This will be beneficial for other members for the similar issue so that they can find and fix their issue.*

We have tried to create a python azure function using timer trigger and figured out as you that we need to have our `function.json` file in below format.

The `function.json` that you are using is:

```
{
    "schedule": "0 30 14 * * *",
    "name": "myTimer",
    "type": "timerTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "runOnStartup": false
}
```

Instead of that We need to specify the `bindings` before adding the value in our `.json` file .
For example:-

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
    "schedule": "0 30 14 * * *",
    "name": "myTimer",
    "type": "timerTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "runOnStartup": false //
}
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py"
}
```

[image]

And then after deploy we will be able to see the timer function in our function app on Portal itself.

[image]

*For more information please refer this* **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**| [***Timer trigger for Azure Functions***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python#configuration).